# Printing a calendar with month and year in C

Tags: c, calendar

I'm trying to make a program that will print out the month from the given year and month that the user inputs. What I have so far just ends up printing out the entire calendar year.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int determineleapyear(int year);
int days_in_month[]= {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
char *months[]=
  {
    " ",
    "\n\n\nJanuary",
    "\n\n\nFebruary",
    "\n\n\nMarch",
    "\n\n\nApril",
    "\n\n\nMay",
    "\n\n\nJune",
    "\n\n\nJuly",
    "\n\n\nAugust",
    "\n\n\nSeptember",
    "\n\n\nOctober",
    "\n\n\nNovember",
    "\n\n\nDecember"
  };

int determinedaycode(int year)
{
  int d1, d2, d3;
  d1 = year/4.0;
  d2 = year/100.;
  d3 = year/400.;
  return 1 + (year + d1 + d2 + d3 + 1) % 7;
}

int determineleapyear(int year) 
{
    return (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0));
}

void calendar(int year, int month, int daycode)
{
    int day;
    printf("%s", months[month]);
    printf("\n\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

      //Correct the position for the first date
      for (day = 1; day <= 1 + daycode * 5; day++)
    {
      printf(" ");
    }

      //Print all the dates for one month
      for (day = 1; day <= days_in_month[month]; day++)
    {
      printf("%2d", day);

      //Is day before Sat? Else start next line Sun.
      if ((day + daycode) % 7 > 0)
        printf("   ");
      else
        printf("\n ");
    }
      // Set position for next month
      daycode = (daycode + days_in_month[month]) % 7;

      if (determineleapyear(year))
        days_in_month[2] = 29;
      printf("\n     %s %d\n", months[month], year);
}

//------------------------------------------
int main() {
  int daycode, month, year;

   printf("\nEnter the month: ");
   scanf("%d", &month);
   if (month < 1 || month > 12)
   {
        printf("Error: month must be in range 1..12");
        return printf("\nEnter the month: ");
        scanf("%d", &month);
   }

   printf("\nEnter the year: ");
   scanf("%d", &year);
   if (year < 0)
   {
        printf("Error: year must be > 0");
        return scanf("%d", &year);
   }

   daycode = determinedaycode(year);
   calendar(year, month, daycode);
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me out with making it print just one month?

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using? This code won't compile for several reasons. One is that print_a_month accepts three parameters and you are only passing one. Another is that print_a_month returns an integer, but you are not returning anything. Can you post the actual code or a representative sample thereof?

Comment: @BrettWolfington I edited it, sorry, the code I had before was me just trying to figure out how to do it. This is the code I'm using

Answer (score 1):

Your `calendar` function is running a loop from 1 to 12, which is causing all months to be printed. Remove the loop and replace it with a parameter to allow the user to select a month:

```
void calendar(int year, int month, int daycode)
{
    int day;

    printf("%s", months[month]);
    printf("\n\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

    //Correct the position for the first date
    for (day = 1; day <= 1 + daycode * 5; day++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    //Print all the dates for one month
    for (day = 1; day <= days_in_month[month]; day++)
    {
        printf("%2d", day);

        //Is day before Sat? Else start next line Sun.
        if ((day + daycode) % 7 > 0)
            printf("   ");
        else
            printf("\n ");
    }

    // Set position for next month
    daycode = (daycode + days_in_month[month]) % 7;
}
```

Call it in main using the variable read from input:

```
calendar(year, month, daycode);
```

I would also highly recommend validating input. Something like the following:

```
printf("\nEnter the month: ");
scanf("%d", &month);
if (month < 1 || month > 12)
{
    printf("Invalid month selected");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Updated my code above. Made all the corrections you've recommended to make. My only issue now is that I tried getting the leapyear function to work, but it's not. Instead it's just making the name and year of the month show up under the month...
And I'd also like the program to re-ask the user for the month/year if they enter an incorrect  number. I tried doing it, but it didn't work...

Comment: @user3434743: since you call the leap year function after you finished printing, it isn't surprising it doesn't do much.  Try calling it before you do the printing.  Or, more relevantly, call it inside the per-month calendar routine when the month is February.